# how to send json data to html page in node.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

my function **"fus.listjson"** that generate json data i wants to send specific html page.So  i perform such operation, how can i solve this problem.

```
app.get('/list/json',fus.listjson);
```

currently i used socket connection. I does not want to use socket connection any other methods in node.js to handle this task.

```
socket.emit('ffusdata', { fusdata: fus.listjson});
```

plz help 
how do i go above this.
thank's in advance

Comment: is that a websocket? are you using `socket.io`? what's the problem with your approach? what's your client's code?

Comment: when i using socket.io the html page received data from socket was blinking. I work on realtime data, so i want to received the data without blinking the page .....

Answer (score 3):

You want to render the JSON as part of a HTML page with other content? You're going to need a template engine with your express application.

EJS is decent (https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) as is Jade. I've included a sample of EJS below.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('xyz', {
    jsondata: YOUR_JSON
  });
});

// xyz.ejs
<% if (jsondata) { %>
  <pre><%= jsondata %></pre>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using express, since you have app.get. In that case just use the json method on the response object:

```
app.get("/list/json", function(req, res) {
    res.json(fus.listjson);
});
```

Comment: my above method "app.get('/list/json',fus.listjson);" return json data on web when i typing url "/list/json" on web browser...

Comment: i want to send that json data on specific html page like xyz.html